# Unit test in a PHP class method - Dependency with class attribute?

Tags: php, unit-testing, class

Say I have this class:

```
class MyExample
{
   public $my_var = [1,2,3,4];

   public function MyMethod() 
   {
     //Here I use $this->my_var;
   }
}
```

What would be a good way to test the method MyMethod, taking into account that I use the class property $my_var in it.  Would you suggest passing the class property as an argument to the method? So I can "give arguments, get a result" approach?:

```
  public function MyMethod($my_var) 
   {
     //Here I use $my_var;
   }
```

I have a feeling that if I don't do that, if I want to test MyMethod, I would have to create several instances of MyExample with different values of `$my_var` and that would be somehow testing the class itself, and not just the method.

What would be a good approach?

Comment: Imo, simply using $this->my_var is better if you're just updating the variable within the class, if you're passing in data from outside of the class, then you'd add that as a parameter in the function instead.

Comment: So, then for each time I want to test the method with different values, I would have to create a new instance of the class with a new value for that property, right?

Comment: The scope of that variable is private, so you can't set the value of it like `$MyExample->my_var or MyExample::my_var`. You can only update that variable from within the scope of the function by passing some data in and mutating it with a class function; when you do this, you're not re-instantiating the class, unless you're calling a mutator method from outside the scope of the class.

Comment: That was my bad. That variable is public. The question is rather broad though. I am trying to realize when we say Unit, what do we do when we have dependencies with the class itself, like values in the properties of the class that are used within the methods.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Unit' in 'Unit Test' is best thought of as the class itself.  You should be able to refactor the internal implementation of the class extensively, while leaving its public API the same, without breaking your tests.  In fact, that's basically what they're for: to allow you to make changes to the *implentation* of the unit, safe in the knowledge you will be told if you have changed the way it works from the perspective of *other classes* in your system.